# How to use hashmap or other better methods to remove duplicate strings from a set of string?

Tags: python, algorithm, hash, hashmap

I have a string datasets that include over 20 million set of strings, the length of string vary from 50 to 5000, now I want to remove duplicate (or very similar) string within them. I found `faiss` may solve this question, but not sure if it is correct, here is my solution,

```
np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.random((1000, 128)).astype('float32')

use_gpu = faiss.get_num_gpus() > 0

index = faiss.GpuIndexFlatL2(faiss.StandardGpuResources(), 128) if use_gpu else faiss.IndexFlatL2(128)

index.add(data)
query_vector = np.random.random((1, 128)).astype('float32')
k = 5  
distances, indices = index.search(query_vector, k)

print("the cloest index：", indices)
print("distance is：", distances)
```

the problem is I need to encode my string firstly then put it into `index`? I think it still cost time

Any suggestion is helpful for me.